# HTML5 storage methods are not working in iPad private mode

Tags: local-storage, session-storage

I have implemented session storage feature using amplify.js library, The storage is not working on iPad private mod, It working as expected in non-private mode.

So, I have implemented cookie in fall back if your browser is not supporting storage. I should able to store data in json/js object format and I feel cookie is not efficient here.

I also have another way i.e. storing my json data in some global object and use it as required in my views.

Is there any other way excluding above 2 way to do this?